# how can i display the latest items from another site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, web-part, cross-site-publishing

I have a web application, with three site collections . and i want inside my team site to be able to display the latest pages that  have been added to my enterprise wiki site collection. so what are the available approaches which i can follow?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Create an External list and add a list view webpart. You will have the SharePoint user experience.

You can use SharePoint Designer as well as Visual Studio for this.

This is how to do using Visual Studio:

[Create SharePoint 2013 External List using Visual Studio 2012](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/07/sharepoint-2013-external-list.html)

[Create an External List Using C#](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/07/create-external-list.html)

[Modifying BDC Model Entity in Business Connectivity Services](http://www.malindesilva.net/2014/08/modify-bcs-entity.html)

[Here](http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/02/23/walkthrough-create-a-simple-bcs-connection-with-sharepoint-designer-2010/) is how to do it using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: but can i do the same , by going to my site setting -->select add app of type "External List"?

Comment: Yes for that you need to create an external content type. I have mentioned how to make that external content type as well

Comment: but if i am not wrong , creating an external content type, requires connecting to a Database tables. so how i can know which table i need to use ? and second question how i will be deploying the external content type from staging to live? in this way i need to chnage the database server name to match the live database server ? can u advice?

Comment: i though i can define an external content type, by speficying which library i want to display the latest items from, rather than connecting to the DB...

Comment: External content types are not created just for lists but for many other services including web services.

Comment: so how i can knwo the database name for my enterprise wiki site collection?